# Как сверстать карточку товара без верхнего уголка?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image]

Как сверстать такую карточку товара?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как сверстать карточку товара без верхнего уголка?

Можно через линейный градиент, указав полупрозрачность

---

**Насчет скругления углов + рамки:**

Если не нужен IE и Edge, то через Clip-path.

Если нужен IE и Edge, то как-то так.

Левый нижний и правый верхний уголки не идеальные, но зато решение без усложнений

### Результат

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 25px, #0090D9 25px) top / 100% 5px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 25px, #0090D9 25px) left / 5px 100% no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 17px, #0090D9 17px, #0090D9 22px, #fff 20px);
  border: 5px solid #0090D9;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Тот же код на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/KKPYGeK)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```css
#cart {
 width: 200px;
 height: 370px;
 background: black;
 position: relative;
}
 
#cart:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;    
 border-bottom: 29px solid black;
 border-left: 29px solid #eee;
 border-right: 29px solid #black;
 width: 42px;
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart"></div>
```